# Cygnus stop at start

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I've installed Cygnus on Ubuntu 14.04 using [this guide](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/doc/installation/src_install.md) and when i proceed to start cygnus through(correctly filled):

`nohup APACHE_FLUME_HOME/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf -f APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf/cygnus.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,LOGFILE [-p <mgmt-if-port>] [-t <polling-interval>] &`

I get this output:

```
 Warning: JAVA_HOME is not set!

+ exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx20m -cp '/etc/flume/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf:/etc/flume/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/lib/*:/etc/flume/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*'

-Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf -n cygnusagent 

Starting an ordered shutdown of Cygnus 
Stopping sources
All the channels are empty
Stopping channels Stopping sinks
```

Where is the problem?

Version: 0.8.0

Conf. File:

```
cygnusagent.channel = mysql-channel
cygnusagent.sinks = mysql-sink
cygnusagent.sources = http-source

cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = mysql-channel
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = def_servpath
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts de
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.de.type = es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.interceptors.DestinationExtractor$Builder
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.de.matching_table = /usr/cygnus/conf/matching_table.conf

cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.channel = mysql-channel
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.type = es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.sinks.OrionMySQLSink
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_host = 127.0.0.1
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_port = 3306
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_username = root
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.mysql_password = root
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = row

cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.type = memory
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnusagent.channels.mysql-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

LOG:

> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,475 (main) [INFO -
>   com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication.main(CygnusApplication.java:235)]
>   Starting a Jetty server listening on port 8081 (Management Interface)
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,519 (main) [INFO -
>   org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:67)] Logging to
>   org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via
>   org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,519 (main) [INFO -
>   com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication.main(CygnusApplication.java:238)]
>   Starting Cygnus application
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,528 (Thread-1) [INFO -
>   org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:67)] jetty-6.1.26
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,544 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.start(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:61)]
>   Configuration provider starting
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,559 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:133)]
>   Reloading configuration
>   file:/etc/flume/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/cygnus.conf
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,575 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)]
>   Processing:mysql-sink
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,588 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)]
>   Processing:mysql-sink
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,588 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)]
>   Processing:mysql-sink
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,589 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN -
>   org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1046)]
>   Invalid property specified: channel
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,592 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN -
>   org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.(FlumeConfiguration.java:101)]
>   Configuration property ignored: cygnusagent.channel = mysql-channel
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,593 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)]
>   Processing:mysql-sink
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,593 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:930)]
>   Added sinks: mysql-sink Agent: cygnusagent
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,594 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)]
>   Processing:mysql-sink
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,594 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)]
>   Processing:mysql-sink
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,594 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)]
>   Processing:mysql-sink
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,621 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN -
>   org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.isValid(FlumeConfiguration.java:319)]
>   Agent configuration for 'cygnusagent' does not contain any channels.
>   Marking it as invalid.
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,621 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN -
>   org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:127)]
>   Agent configuration invalid for agent 'cygnusagent'. It will be
>   removed.
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,622 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:140)]
>   Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents:
>   []
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,622 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN -
>   org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:138)]
>   No configuration found for this host:cygnusagent
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,640 (Thread-1) [WARN -
>   org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.warn(Slf4jLog.java:76)] failed
>   SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8081: java.net.BindException: Address already
>   in use
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,652 (Thread-1) [WARN -
>   org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.warn(Slf4jLog.java:76)] failed
>   Server@62526d1d: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,652 (Thread-1) [FATAL -
>   com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.http.JettyServer.run(JettyServer.java:62)]
>   Fatal error running the Management Interface. Details=Address already
>   in use
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,669 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:138)]
>   Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{}
>   channels:{} }
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,723 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.node.Application.stopAllComponents(Application.java:101)]
>   Shutting down configuration: { sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{}
>   channels:{} }
>
> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,724 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO -
>   org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:138)]
>   Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{}
>   channels:{} }

Comment: What are the logs saying? The output you are printing is the standard output. Logs should be located at `/var/log/cygnus` (nevertheless, have a look on what you have configured in the `log4j.properties` in order to know the exact location of the logs). What version of Cygnus are you using? Which is your configuration?

Comment: Added version, logs, and conf file in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this log:

```
2015-05-20 18:51:59,589 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1046)] Invalid property specified: channel
```

There is no channel configured since the property `channel` is invalid. Instead of that, you must use `channels`:

```
cygnusagent.channels = mysql-channel
```

Please, consider using the [Cygnus template](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/release/0.8.0/conf/agent.conf.template) to create your configuration (there is a [section in the README](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/release/0.8.0/README.md#section5.2) about that as well).

Comment: That was a problem but still not working. Should i post the new log here or in a new question?

Comment: I would say another question. Nevertheless, before doing that, try changing all the package names from `es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.*` to `com.telefonica.iot.*`; from 0.8.0 those package names chaned ;)

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem of the log is :

> 2015-05-20 18:51:59,652 (Thread-1) [FATAL - com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.http.JettyServer.run(JettyServer.java:62)] Fatal error running the Management Interface. Details=Address already in use

This is due to a trash process produced in one of the trials of running cygnus. Solved by killing the process.

Also made the changes suggested in the other response to clean all warns.

Comment: That issue is identified and fixed in newest releases of Cygnus (> 0.8.0). Anyway, it didn't affect Cygnus, despite of the FATAL level of the log :)